# GIS Traveltime based on cost

Tags: gis, qgis, grass

http://bit.ly/1Ksy3dq < here you will find .pdf and 1st picture there is what I need. It shows how much time would man need to travel from one point to another if we consider relief. I need to make it on different location. Ive done slope and aspect and used r.walk, but r.walk displays only cost based on surface and it doesnt have to do anything with time. Ive heard of some command called r.traveltime, but it doesnt work in any version of QGIS or GRASS GIS. I hope you understand what I want here, and I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think [r.walk](http://grass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/manuals/r.walk.html) is what you need. The result is walking time in seconds.